# aggregate less efficient than loops?

Tags: r, loops, aggregate

I was trying to do this operation on a big table, to count rows with different combinations of a and b in a data.table X.

```
Y <- aggregate(c ~ a+b,X,length)
```

And it was taking forever (I stopped after 30 min) though RAM usage was still.

Then I tried to loop manually through values of `b` and aggregate only on `a` (technically still aggregating on `b` but with a single value of `b` every time) :

```
sub_agg <- list()
unique_bs <- unique(X$b)
for (b_it in unique_bs){
sub_agg[[length(sub_agg)+1]] <- aggregate(c ~ a + b,subset(X, b == b_it),length)
}
Y <- do.call(rbind, sub_agg )
```

And I was done in 3 min.

I may as well go further and get rid of aggregate completely and only do operations on subsets.

Is aggregate less efficient than nested loops and operations on subsets or is this a special case ?

Aggregations are often the parts of codes that take the most time, so I'm now thinking of always trying loops instead, I'd like to understand better what's happening here.

Additional info:

> X has 20 million rows
>
> 50 distinct values for b
>
> 15 000 distinct values for a

Comment: You've lost something in your second approach (only you will know if it's important) - `aggregate` sorts the output, in this case by `Y$b`, then `Y$a`, whereas your loop leaves `Y$b` in the order in which it occurred in `X`

Comment: you should consider using [tag:data.table]. In the case of length, you can do `library(data.table); setDT(X)[, .N, by=c("a", "b")]`, it's ~3.5 times faster than `table` (using JorisMeys example data) and of course you can put any operation instead of `.N` (which tells the number of observations)

Comment: Fantastic, it's faster including conversion ?

Comment: you can directly import your data (faster) with `fread` but yes, conversion is very very fast anyway (the conversion was included in the function for the benchmark). You can have a look [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html) for an introduction to [tag:data.table]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, aggregate is less efficient than the loops you use there, because:

- aggregate becomes disproportionally slower when the number of data points increases. Your second solution uses `aggregate` on small subsets. One of the
  reasons is that `aggregate` depends on sorting, and sorting is not done in O(n) time.
- aggregate also uses `expand.grid` internally, which creates a data frame with all possible combinations of all unique values in the variables a and b. You can see this in the internal code of `aggregate.data.frame`. Also this function becomes disproportionally slower with rising number of observations.
- *edit: my last point didn't really make sense as you do combine everything in a data frame.*

That said, there is absolutely no reason to use `aggregate` here. I come to the data frame `Y` by simply using `table` :

```
thecounts <- with(X, table(a,b))
Y <- as.data.frame(thecounts)
```

This solution is a whole lot faster than the solution you came up with using `aggregate`. 68 times on my machine to be precise...

Benchmark:

```
        test replications elapsed relative 
1  aggloop()            1   15.03   68.318 
2 tableway()            1    0.22    1.000
```

code for benchmarking (note I made everything a bit smaller to not block my R
for too long):

```
nrows <- 20e5

X <- data.frame(
  a = factor(sample(seq_len(15e2), nrows, replace = TRUE)),
  b = factor(sample(seq_len(50), nrows, replace = TRUE)),
  c = 1
)

aggloop <- function(){
sub_agg <- list()
unique_bs <- unique(X$b)
for (b_it in unique_bs){
  sub_agg[[length(sub_agg)+1]] <- aggregate(c ~ a + b,subset(X, b == b_it),length)
}
Y <- do.call(rbind, sub_agg )
}

tableway <- function(){
  thecounts <- with(X, table(a,b))
  Y <- as.data.frame(thecounts)
}

library(rbenchmark)

benchmark(aggloop(),
          tableway(),
          replications = 1
          )
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot. So in this case I should use table as I'm only counting rows, but if I need to sum or average, a solution with loops similar to what i did would be appropriate wouldn't it ?

Comment: +1, `count(X, a, b)` from `dplyr` get roughly the same result as `table`, but is roughly twice as slow. But still, 0.4 secs on 20e6 records is still a lot faster than 3 minutes :).

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper I'd rather use `tapply` than `aggregate` as that one's quite a lot faster in my experience. Or you could move to the `dplyr` package, that one is seriously optimized and -to my own surprise- in many cases faster than the base R function `tapply`.

Comment: @JorisMeys I just tried `count` from `dplyr`, it is a bit slower than `table` but still very fast in comparison to `aggregate`.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra `count` is slower than `table`, but when you need to apply more complex functions to a data frame, `dplyr` often gives you more efficient solutions.

Comment: The proposed solution with table and as.data.frame includes all combination of a and b, even if they don't exist in X, so we find zeroes in the resulting data.frame and its number or f rows is the product of the number of unique a's and b's. This data.frame could become huge if a and b had more distinct values. So the scale of the gain of performance here may partly be explained by the low amount of distinct b's in the example. With aggregate and length only existing combinations are returned.

Comment: just for the record, using [tag:data.table] is ~3.5 times faster than `table` ;-)

Comment: @Cath feel free to illustrate this in an answer. I'm too lazy.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @JorisMeys and to illustrate my comment(s), another way of achieving what you're after is to use [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table), which is very efficient in manipulating large data.

The general form of `data.table` syntax is, `DT` being a `data.table`: `DT[i, j, by]`, meaning *"Take DT, subset rows using i, then calculate j, grouped by by"*.
For example, the code to get the counts by each `a` and `b` level in `X` is: `X[, .N, by=c("a", "b")]`.

You can read more about `data.table` in [this introduction to the package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html).

If we want to benchmark `data.table` way with the other ways, using the same example data X and the functions defined in JorisMeys' answer:

```
library(data.table)
X2 <- copy(X) # taking a copy of X so the conversion to data.table does not impact the initial data

dtway <- function(){
            setDT(X2)[, .N, by=c("a", "b")] # setDT permits to convert X2 into a data.table
         }

library(rbenchmark)
benchmark(aggloop(),
          tableway(),
          dtway(),
          replications = 1)

        # test replications elapsed relative
# 1  aggloop()            1   17.29  192.111
# 3    dtway()            1    0.09    1.000
# 2 tableway()            1    0.27    3.000
```

**Note:** the efficiencies are dependent on the data, I tried several `X` (with different random seeds) and found relative efficiency from 1/2.5 to 1/3.5 for `data.table` relative to `base` `R` with `table`.